# SQL to display keys of leading, lagging record

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have data in table that can presented by SQL as below :

```
SELECT T.VERSION_ID T_VERSION_ID
                ,cast(T.START_DATE As Date) as T_START_DATE
                ,cast(ISNULL( LEAD (START_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE),'9999-12-31') As Date) as CALC_END_DATE_LEAD
                ,cast(ISNULL( LAG  (START_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE),'9999-12-31') As Date) as CALC_END_DATE_LAG
FROM(select 'Vrandom1' as VERSION_ID
            ,cast('22-MAR-2018' As Date) as start_date
            ,'9999-12-31' as end_date
            , 1 as is_approved
    union
    select 'Vrandom2' as VERSION_ID
           ,cast('28-MAR-2018' As Date) as start_date
           ,'9999-12-31' as end_date
           ,1 as is_approved
    union
    select 'Vrandom3' as VERSION_ID
          ,cast('25-MAR-2018' As date) as start_date
          ,'9999-12-31' as end_date
          ,1 as is_approved
    ) as T
```

**Output**

```
T_VERSION_ID  T_START_DATE CALC_END_DATE_LEAD                CALC_END_DATE_LAG

Vrandom1                           22/03/2018                         25/03/2018                                         31/12/9999
Vrandom3                           25/03/2018                         28/03/2018                                         22/03/2018
Vrandom2                           28/03/2018                         31/12/9999                                         25/03/2018
```

This table is used inside application where one record say with version "Vrandom3" will be in effect.  For processing, I need to find keys of immediate leading and lagging record as per start date.  i.e. I would need to display Vrandom2 and Vrandom1 as the keys of leading and lagging record.

Desired result in the application:

```
T_VERSION_ID  T_START_DATE    CALC_END_DATE_LEAD   CALC_END_DATE_LAG   key_leading   key_lagging

Vrandom3      25/03/2018      28/03/2018           22/03/2018          Vrandom2      Vrandom1
```

or

```
T_VERSION_ID  T_START_DATE   CALC_END_DATE_LEAD   CALC_END_DATE_LAG   key_leading   key_lagging

Vrandom1      22/03/2018     25/03/2018           31/12/9999          Vrandom3      null
```

I can think of joining inline views based on start_date but is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense at all. What is the business logic you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Title and query suggest "SQL Server", tag says "and Oracle". Which one is it?

Comment: Removed the Oracle tag (since your example use the `TOP` keyword which is not valid in Oracle and neither is using `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause). If it should be tagged Oracle then please edit your question to put it back in and make it clear why you have tagged it.

Comment: Sean, I need to fire update on lagging and leading record. that's why I need to display their keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding:

```
,LEAD (key_col) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE),'9999-12-31') As Date) as Key_col_LEAD
,LAG (key_col) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE),'9999-12-31') As Date) as Key_col_LAG
```

to your SELECT

Comment: Thank You !!! This was the portion I was missing that I could use any column in LEAD or LAG. Appreciated your help.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to display key of record with First and Last value ? When I tried :    
,FIRST_VALUE(VERSION_ID) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS fv
,LAST_VALUE(VERSION_ID) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS lv

I got Result as :
fv   lv
Vrandom1 Vrandom1
Vrandom1 Vrandom3
Vrandom1 Vrandom2

fv looks as expected but not sure what's happening with LAST_VALUE :

I would expect : Vrandom2 for all 3 records

Comment: Why?  vrandom2 has the highest start date, which should come least in ORDER BY START_DATE, I think.

Comment: Yes, It should come in LAST_VALUE for all 3 records. But I get "Vrandom3 Vrandom1 Vrandom2" Instead of "Vrandom2 Vrandom2 Vrandom2 ". Thanks

Comment: Adding "ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING" in LAST_VALUE gives the correct result : add : FIRST_VALUE  (VERSION_ID) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) as fv
    , LAST_VALUE  (VERSION_ID) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as lv in first sql. I couldn't paste complete sql because of char limit.

Answer (score 1):

[LAG (there's also LEAD) windowing function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

> Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the
>   use of a self-join starting with SQL Server 2012. LAG provides access
>   to a row at a given physical offset that comes before the current row.
>   Use this analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in
>   the current row with values in a previous row.

These functions are designed to get leading and lagging rows.

Example from the link:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT BusinessEntityID, YEAR(QuotaDate) AS SalesYear, SalesQuota AS CurrentQuota,   
       LAG(SalesQuota, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(QuotaDate)) AS PreviousQuota  
FROM Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory  
WHERE BusinessEntityID = 275 and YEAR(QuotaDate) IN ('2005','2006');
```

Comment: May you want to expand your answer as to explain why does this solve OP's question? Especially because, having this MS custom of changing their docs URL on a regular basis or archiving things, your answer might render useless in the future

Comment: I am already using lag and lead functions in my sql. I need to list keys of lagging and leading record.

Comment: You can include those in your query.  you already have two columns using lag/lead.  Is there any reason you can't add the key columns too?

Comment: user1443098, I need keys of lagging or leading rows based on start_date. Could you please elaborate how I can do that ?